# Union not picking up all ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some challenges with a Union not working in a big macro. It's supposed to join together a few ranges but it only seems to pick up the first range. To help isolate the challenge I've trimmed all the code down to this:

```
Dim copiedrange As Range
Dim SrcWB As Workbook
Dim SrcWS As Worksheet

Set SrcWB = Workbooks("all-euro-data-2018-2019 (1)")
Set SrcWS = SrcWB.Sheets("E1")

i = 1

Set copiedrange = Union(SrcWS.Range("A" & i & ":F" & i), SrcWS.Range("AX" & i), _
SrcWS.Range("AZ" & i), SrcWS.Range("BH" & i & ":BJ" & i))

MsgBox copiedrange.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

For some reason the column count is coming back as 6 (A to F) when I think it should be higher to account for all the other ranges. What am I missing/getting wrong/being an idiot about???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Union` is working absolutely fine. For example, `MsgBox copiedRange.Address` returns `$A$1:$F$1,$AX$1,$AZ$1,$BH$1:$BJ$1`.

You're encountering the behavior of `Range.Columns`.`Columns.Count` is returning the number of columns in the first **area** (`$A$1:$F$1`).

From the [`Range.Columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columns) documentation:

> When applied to a `Range` object that's a multiple-area selection, this property returns columns from only the first area of the range. For example, if the `Range` object has two areas — `A1:B2` and `C3:D4` — `Selection.Columns.Count` returns 2, not 4. To use this property on a range that may contain a multiple-area selection, test `Areas.Count` to determine whether the range contains more than one area. If it does, loop over each area in the range.